# How can I include the .dll files when I pack my Windows form project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winforms

I uploaded a school project which I coded with C++ Windows form. The program runs well on my computer. However, when my friends run my program, they got three missing .dll files which are VCRUNTIME140D.dll, MSVCP140D.dll, and ucrtbased.dll.
Is there anyway to include these .dll files when I pack my project so that other people can run the program right after they install it?

I tried searching many websites and can't fix my problem.

Comment: You need to ship the [Visual C++ Redistributable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist) installer with your app.

Comment: VCRUNTIME140D.dll, MSVCP140D.dll, and ucrtbased.dll are the **DEBUG** versions of those dlls, which is why you are getting the issue. Build your project as a **Release** build.

Comment: Note that it is a license violation to copy the debug DLLs separately. They are only available when Visual Studio is installed on a computer. Also note that installing the "Redistributable" is a one time thing - once it is done, it works for all programs.

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

The VCRUNTIME140D.dll, MSVCP140D.dll, and ucrtbased.dll you refer to are the debug versions of the Visual Studio VC++ dlls, you can tell this by the last character in those dlls "D" i.e. MSVCP140**D**.dll.

The release versions are named, VCRUNTIME140.dll, MSVCP140.dll, and ucrtbase.dll

When distributing your project as an .exe you should build it in "Release" mode, then ask your friends to install the latest [Visual Studio 2022 VC++ Redist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist)

Comment: "then ask your friends to install the latest Visual Studio 2022 VC++ Redist" - or include it in your .MSI installation package and automatically run/install it alongside your application.